# Doing an Android Silent Mode App, can't even start Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, galaxy

I'm working with the Android Application Development for Dummies book by Donn Felker. Specifically, I'm working with the Silent Mode App.

It should be simple to follow the instructions step by step, but as it turns out I can't even start the main activity without crashing the app. I must've gone over my code a dozen times and I can't still figure out what's wrong and make it work without LogCat firing errors like crazy.

Debug device is a Samsung Galaxy SII w/ Android 4.0.3.

Here's the MainAcitivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button m_toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
AudioManager m_audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
boolean m_isPhoneSilent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkMode();
    toggleImage();
    generateClick();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    checkMode();
    toggleImage();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;


}

private void checkMode()
{
    m_audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(m_audio.getRingerMode())
    {
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            m_isPhoneSilent = false;
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
            m_isPhoneSilent = true;
            break;
    }

}

private void generateClick()
{
    m_toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (m_isPhoneSilent == true)
                {
                    m_audio.setRingerMode
                    (AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    m_isPhoneSilent = false;
                }
            else
                {
                    m_audio.setRingerMode
                    (AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    m_isPhoneSilent = true;
                }
            toggleImage();
        }
    });
}

private void toggleImage()
{
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
    Drawable newAsset;

    if (m_isPhoneSilent == true)
    {
        newAsset = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
    }
    else
    {
        newAsset = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
    }

    imageView.setImageDrawable(newAsset);

}
```

I've tried to debug, but I haven't found the problem. Please help.

Comment: What errors does logcat show? Where do you initialize your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button m_toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton); //<<<< here
//....your code
```

you are trying to find Button before setting layout for Activity so move it after setting `setContentView` as :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button m_toggleButton ;
AudioManager m_audio;
boolean m_isPhoneSilent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     m_toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    m_audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
   ///... your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call this

```
Button m_toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
AudioManager m_audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

before your `setContentView` change it to this:

```
Button m_;
AudioManager m_audio;
boolean m_isPhoneSilent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    m_audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    ....
```